# Laravel won't save variable to database via mobile brave browser

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, brave-browser

Edit: Removing the brave shields didn't correct the issue on mobile.  Hard coding the variable does work (even though dumping the variable shows the variable is the same value as the hard coded value).

I have a section of a controller that receives the routes within the url and then saves the variables into the database. This is done through a get route.  Below is an obfuscated version of the code.

```
public function getDataAndSave($handle, $integer=null){

    $value = array('id' => $id,
            'integer' => $integer,
    );   

    $ValueToUpdate = Table::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

    if(isset($ValueToUpdate->id)){
        $ValueToUpdate->update([
            'integer' => isset($value['integer']) ? $value['integer'] : $ValueToUpdate->integer,
            'text' => isset($value['text']) ? $value['text'] : $ValueToUpdate->text
        ]);
    }
}

//Route looks like this
Route::get('update-value/{handle}/{integer?}', ['middleware' => [],
            'uses' => 'UpdateValueController@getDataAndSave',
            'as' => 'UpdateValue.view',
            'roles' => []]
```

**The Issue**
This works fine in the Brave and other browsers on my laptop, but if I run it using brave browser on my mobile device, the $integer value saves as 0, while the text value saves as expected.  When I vardump the $integer or $value variables, it will show the proper integer, even when using the problematic browser on my phone.   If I turn off the Brave Browser's Shields then it works.  If I hard code an integer value instead of updating the integer variable using $integer like this:

```
    $ValueToUpdate->update([
        'integer' => isset($value['integer']) ? 5 : $ValueToUpdate->integer,
    ]);
```

It saves the 5 as I'd expect.

I know this is bad practice, but I'm saving this specific dataa within a get route (not a post).

Has anyone experienced something like this before and have a solution?  I'm going to toggle each shield protection from brave to find the cause, but thought I'd ask here in case someone experiences a similar issue in the future.

Additionally, here is the screenshot of my vardump on the object being saved after it's saved on my mobile phone.   You'll see that there is a "changes" section of my collection and it shows the variable rating set to 5 even though the save made by eloquent is saving 0.
[image]

Comment: This doesn’t make much sense. The only thing that could differ here, is what the browser sends to begin with - but if you say, that dumping the variable shows that it is filled correctly, then we are past that point already.

Comment: _“When I vardump the $integer or $value variables, it will show the proper integer, even when using the problematic browser on my phone.”_ - does that mean it showed something like `5` as the _value_, or did it explicitly say that the _type_ was `int` as well?

Comment: @CBroe, it shows the actual integer.  In my example it was 5.  I dump it just before the update and it shows the 5.  I even thought it could potentially be something with the format of the variable so I encased it in intval() to see if that helps at all. It's very bizarre.

Comment: var_dump also shows what _type_ a variable is, and that’s what I was asking …

Comment: All you have shown us so far is a function that takes this as a parameter. How/where do you _read_ the actual value that was send by the client?

Comment: The data is read from the url.  I've included the route details to the question now.

Comment: Have you checked what gets send to the server in the first place, using browser dev tools? And compared that between shields up/shields down mode?

Comment: Sorry I missed that prior comment one second and I'll send it over.

Comment: @CBroe running gettype on the variable returns "integer" and the variable set is 5.